# Priority queue comparator on object with const member

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++

I'm trying to implement a priority queue which uses an object which has a const member that is used to define the priority of objects in the queue. The following is a stripped down version of what I'm using

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

class Event {
public:
    Event(float _time) : time(_time) {};
    const float time;
};

struct EventComp {
public:
    bool operator()(const Event& a, const Event& b) const {
      return a.time < b.time;
    }
};

class EventQueue {
private:
    std::priority_queue<Event, std::vector<Event>, EventComp> events;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    EventQueue q;
}
```

When I try to compile (using g++ -std=c++11), I get the following error messages, which I don't quite understand.

```
g++ -std=c++11 events.cpp -o events
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/queue:62:0,
                 from events.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_heap.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::__adjust_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _Distance, _Distance, _Tp, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Event*, std::vector<Event> >; _Distance = long int; _Tp = Event; _Compare = EventComp]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_heap.h:448:15:   required from ‘void std::make_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Event*, std::vector<Event> >; _Compare = EventComp]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_queue.h:411:48:   required from ‘std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::priority_queue(const _Compare&, _Sequence&&) [with _Tp = Event; _Sequence = std::vector<Event>; _Compare = EventComp]’
events.cpp:15:7:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_heap.h:315:29: error: use of deleted function ‘Event& Event::operator=(Event&&)’
    *(__first + __holeIndex) = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*(__first + __secondChild));
                             ^
events.cpp:4:7: note: ‘Event& Event::operator=(Event&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class Event {
       ^
events.cpp:4:7: error: non-static const member ‘const float Event::time’, can’t use default assignment operator
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/queue:62:0,
                 from events.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_heap.h:321:29: error: use of deleted function ‘Event& Event::operator=(Event&&)’
    *(__first + __holeIndex) = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*(__first
                             ^
```

I assume that some part of the internal structure of the `priority_queue` needs the move assignment operator to insert elements, but the `const` member seems to prevent that operator from being defined. I tried using the rule of five, but it didn't seem to work out. What do I need to add to the class definitions to get this working?

edit: I'm aware that I can remove the `const` qualifier from the member variable, make it `private`, and add an accessor member function to get the value of the variable, but I would rather have it `public` and `const`, so I'm interested in solutions which keep the member variable as it is in the example (if that is even possible).

Comment: FWIW its works on [_`clang`_](http://rextester.com/CULSS5171)

Comment: to narrow down the problem see if `vector<Event>` compiles

Comment: A number of `vector` and `priority_queue` operations requires `MoveAssignable`. In your case with a `const` data member there's pretty much no way to give it sensible assignment semantics. Make `time` non-const and if you want to avoid modifications, make it private and provide a getter instead.

Comment: A more inefficient alternative, if you insist on keeping the `const`, is to add a level of indirection by using a `priority_queue` of, e.g., `unique_ptr<Event>`, and adjusting your comparator accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default constructor of `std::priority_queue<Event, ...>` requires `Event` to be `MoveAssignable` because it calls `std::make_heap` (which has this requirement).  `Event` is not `MoveAssignable` because of the `const float time` data member.  If you remove the `const` qualifier from this data member, your code should compile.

> I'm aware that I can remove the `const` qualifier from the member
>   variable, make it `private`, and add an accessor member function to
>   get the value of the variable, but I would rather have it `public` and
>   `const`, so I'm interested in solutions which keep the member variable
>   as it is in the example (if that is even possible).

Ultimately, to use this std::lib facility, `Event` will *have* to be `MoveAssignable`.  This requirement can be met with either a move assignment operator, or a copy assignment operator.  Either or both of these can be supplied by you, or the compiler.  But when you have a `const` data member, the compiler supplied special member will be implicitly deleted.

Go ahead and supply your own copy and/or move assignment operator if you desire:

```
class Event {
public:
    Event(float _time) : time(_time) {};
    const float time;

    Event(Event&&) = default;
    Event& operator=(Event&&);  // Supply this
};
```

I do not have a good guess as to what you might want the move (or copy) assignment operator to do, since you have stated that once constructed, you do not want `time` to ever change.  That is a design decision which you must work out (and has more to do with software design in general, than C++ syntax).

---

`<aside>`

In the comments of the question [POW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870232/p0w) notes that the code in the question compiles with clang (more accurately, with [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org)).  The reason for this is a *nearly* conforming extension in libc++:

The standard specifies this `priority_queue` constructor:

```
explicit priority_queue(const Compare& x = Compare(),
                        Container&& c = Container());
```

which calls `std::make_heap` with the container `c`.  But the standard also gives leeway to implementors to replace member function signatures with default values, with equivalent overloads.  libc++ replaces this single signature with the following three:

```
priority_queue();
explicit priority_queue(const Compare& x);
explicit priority_queue(const Compare& x, Container&& c);
```

And only the 3rd needs to call `std::make_heap`.  Thus the default constructor in libc++ places fewer requirements on the `value_type`.

I said *nearly* conforming.  The part that is not completely conforming is that the default constructor is not declared `explicit`.  This was a conscious design decision on the part of the implementor to make `priority_queue` easier to use.

`</aside>`

Comment: Hmm, are you sure making the default ctor of the container adaptors `explicit` wasn't a defect? The container default ctors used to be `explicit` too until fixed in a DR.

Comment: OTOH, they have no `initializer_list` constructors, which is I guess why [LWG 2193](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2193) skipped them.

Comment: @T.C.:  I'm sure it *is* a defect.  It just hasn't been reported yet. ;-)